# start and stop C#

Tags: c#, arduino, reset

I have a `DataGridView` with different numbers. Every time I press start, the selected row will be sent to my Arduino.

Now I want to press start and every row, I select will be sent right away until I press stop.

```
private void btn_start_auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isConnected)
    {
        port.Write("#TEXT" + length_txt.Text + "#\n");
    }
}

private void btn_up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        selectedRow--;
        if (selectedRow < 0)
        {
            selectedRow = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to "set" the Start "signal" and and reset it with my Stop button.

Comment: So what are you having problems with?

Comment: Declare a boolean variable with the name **Working** or whatever name is it.
Change the value of the variable to true on clicking start and false on clicking stop
Use SelectionChanged event of DataGridView and make sure that the value of variable is true before sending data.

Comment: Just change `if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)` to `while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)`  (And remove rows from your grid inside the loop)

Comment: @Youssef13 how to declare a boolean variable? This is the way i am looking for. thx

Comment: It's strange that you have written the above code and don't know how to declare a boolean variable. Anyway, It's like `bool Working = false;`

Answer (score -1):

you most write your code in event grid row click Maybe row click even